# PHPUnit mocking function so it is not called

Tags: php, phpunit

I am new to php and writing some test code to learn PHPUnit but I have bit a bit of an issue

I have a class that does a simple function call

```
$this->updateSavedDate($effectiveDate, $customerID);
```

That function has a few database calls to save the date the customer logged in so I want to mock this with:

```
    public function testFunctionIsNotCalled()
{
    $effectiveDate = '2020-03-03';
    $customerID = 123456789;

    $mockClient = $this->getMock(
        'MyFirstClass',
        array('updateSavedDate')
    );

        $mockClient
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('updateSavedDate')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

       $mockClient->enable($effectiveDate, $customerID);

}
```

This fails with

There was 1 error:

```
1) MyFirstClassTest::testFunctionIsNotCalled
Db_ConnectException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out
```

The database code is in the updateSavedDate which I dont want called, how can I mock this correctly so that when it is hit it just does nothing and carry's on

Comment: Not entirely sure, but should your last line be calling `$mockClient->updateSavedDate(...`

Comment: enable is the class name that the function call is in tried changing but got class not found error

Comment: @DarkBacon maybe you need to have a using statement?

Comment: Never, ever, use `'MyFirstClass'`. Instead use `MyFirstClass::class`.